# How to visit a link and stay on it for specific seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, url, python-requests

I have a problem from staying on a website link and that link got a timer for staying and don't move to another place. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = input('Please enter your link: ')
def get_response(url, method='GET'):
    response = requests.request(method, url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win32; x86) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"}, timeout=15)
    text_response = response.text
    status_code = response.status_code
    return[status_code, text_response]
while True:
    (status_code, text_response) = get_response(url)
    parse_data = BeautifulSoup(text_response, 'html.parser')
    time.sleep(20)
    print('done')
    exit()
```

The link will open but not like in browsers

Comment: Try looking at selenium to automate browser activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer runs on a Javascript code on the website, the `requests` library doesn't run the website's Javascript code.

Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead, It allows you to control a browser and run the website's Javascript.